# CSS center between float: left and right inline without width

Tags: html, css, erb

I am really stuck with trying to center a div and have a div floating left and one floating right. In the end it should like somewhat like the first header in the graphic. However the second element, which should be in the center, always floats left like in the second example in the graphic. 
[Example-Graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPb7o.png)

I have been able to center it when I set a the display to block and a specific width. But I want the width to be as large as the children, which I achieve by setting the display to inline-block, right? So is there any other way to do this?

Thanks for any help
Tobias

### HTML

```
<section id="header">
  <div class="content_box logo">
    TippMe-Logo
  </div>
  <div class="content_box user_management">
    <div class="user_icon">

    </div>
    <div class="user_name">
      <%= link_to "USER", "#" %>
    </div>
    <div class="user_logout">
      <%= link_to "(Logout)", "#" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content_box navbar">
    <nav>
      <%= link_to "TIPPEN", "#" %>
      <%= link_to "HIGHSCORE", "#" %>
      <%= link_to "TABELLE", "#" %>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

### CSS

```
// - - - - - VARIABLES - - - - - //

$background: #777777;
$main: #00143A;

// - - - - - GLOBAL STYLING - - - - - //

body{
  background-color: $background;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

#main_wrapper{
  width: 1440px;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 3rem auto 0 auto;
}

.content_box{
  border-radius: 0.6em;
}

// - - - - - HEADER STYLING - - - - - //
#header{
  .content_box{
    background-color: $main;
    padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
    display: inline-block;

  }

  .logo{
    float: left;
    color: white;
  }

  .user_management{
    float: right;
  }

  .navbar{
    margin: 0 auto;
    a{
      float: left;
      padding: 0 10px;
    }
  }

  a{
    color: white;
  }
}
```

Comment: Create a jsfiddle for this.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/thwsegs8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct. Just add one css line.

```
#header{
    text-align: center;
}
```

demo - https://jsfiddle.net/dhananjaymane11/thwsegs8/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this by creating new html and css file. There were few changes which are changed, you were using .user_management instead of .user_name. Increase your .logo width to align .nav in center and .nav width to align .user_name in right corner. You can even use padding it's upto you.

```
<section id="header">
  <div class="content_box logo">
TippMe-Logo
  </div>
  <div class="content_box user_management">
<div class="user_icon">
</div>
 <div class="content_box navbar">
<nav>
  <a href="#"> TIPPEN </a>
  <a href="#"> HIGHSCORE </a>
  <a href="#"> TABELLE </a>
</nav>
</div>
 <div class="user_name">
<a href="#"> USER </a>
</div>
<div class="user_logout">
  <a href="#"> (Logout) </a>
</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Updated CSS

```
body {
background-color: #777777;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.content_box {
  border-radius: 0.6em;
}
#header .content_box {
  background-color: #00143A;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
}
#header .logo {
  float: left;
  color: white;
}
#header .user_name {
  float: left;
}
#header .navbar {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  display:inline;
  float:left;
  width:300px;
}
#header .navbar a {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
#header a {
  color: white;
}
#header{
 width:100%;
 height:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The important part is that the **centered div** comes **after** the left and right divs in the markup. Check out this example, it uses `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` on the centered div, which causes it to be centered.

```css
.left {
    float: left;
    border: solid 1px blue;
}

.mid {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: solid 1px blue;
    text-align: center;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    border: solid 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"> Left </div>
<div class="right"> Right </div>
<div class="mid"> Mid </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **display:flex**

wrap your *content_box* in *div* with the class *flexbox*

```
 <div class="flexBox">
    <div class="content_box navbar">
      <nav>
        <a href="#"> TIPPEN </a>
        <a href="#"> HIGHSCORE </a>
        <a href="#"> TABELLE </a>
      </nav>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Update your **CSS** with the class *flexbox*

```
.flexBox{
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-justify-content: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/thwsegs8/2/

Answer (score -1):

Is this is what you want?

```
img {
max-width: 470px;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: block;
margin: 70px auto;


}
```

Note: Change the values

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get your answer. I don't need any img element. I want to center a div between two other divs. And margin: 0 auto is not working for some reason.